# Hyperelliptic curves defined by rational function in characteristic two

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

I have been looking at hyperelliptic curves over finite field, and there is something I don't figure out. In characteristic different from two, I think it's rather "ok". But in the lecture I am following, we consider some irreducible monic polynomial $\phi$ of odd degree, and the hyperelliptic curve given by :
$$ Y^2+Y = \frac{1}{\phi(T)}$$
But, the definition I have for hyperelliptic curves in characteristic two is given by equations of the form :
$$ y^2+H(x,z)y = F(x,z) $$
where $H, F$ are homogenous of degrees $\deg(H(x,z)) = g+1$ and $\deg(F(x,z)) = 2g+2$ (and then the genus of the curve is $g$), and $H$, $F$ squarefree. We can divide by $H(x,z)^2$ in order to obtain an equation of the form :
$$y^2+y = \frac{F(x,z)}{H(x,z)} $$ 
So, if $z \neq 0$ and $u=\frac{y}{z^{g+1}}, v=\frac{x}{z}$, we have :
$$ u^2 + u = \frac{F(v, 1)}{H(v,1)} = \frac{f(v)}{h(v)}$$

But It doesn't give me what I want. I mean, $\frac{f(v)}{h(v)}$ is not any rational functions, we have some hypothesis on the degrees, for example. How can I relate the equation of the hyperelliptic curves of the beginning with the definition I have of hyperelliptic curve ?

Thank you !

Comment: Something is up with your definition (in the second math-only line): you're writing it using three variables, which would imply that you're working with a projective curve, but your equation is not homogeneous. Additionally, can you include your sources here?

Comment: @KReiser A hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$ is usually thought of as being embedded in weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1, g+1, 1)$. So the equation above is weighted homogeneous. (If you try to homogenize the usual affine equation for a hyperelliptic curve in straight projective space you get a singularity at infinity.)

Comment: @RichardD.James ah, that makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Richard D.James : Exactly, thank you. By the way, I have search in books, and there is an equivalence between separable morphism of degree $2$ : $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ and Artin-Shreier curve for $p=2$. We have aswell an equivalence between Artin-Shreier curve for $p=2$ and hyperelliptic curve in the sense of curve given by equation in the form : $$ y^2 +h(x)y = f(x)$$ with good hypothesis on degrees. But it's this last one equivalence that I don't manage to understand. How can we start with $y^2+y=a(x)$ where $a(x)$ is some rational function and end up with the other one ?